# I am getting the following error while performing web crawling on the IMDB website

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, google-crawlers

```
import re
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from w3lib.url import url_query_cleaner
import extruct

def process_links(links):
    for link in links:
        link.url = url_query_cleaner(link.url)
        yield link

class ImdbCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'imdb'
    allowed_domains = ['www.imdb.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.imdb.com/']
    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                deny=[
                    re.escape('https://www.imdb.com/offsite'),
                    re.escape('https://www.imdb.com/whitelist-offsite'),
                ],
            ),
            process_links=process_links,
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=True
        ),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        return {
            'url': response.url,
            'metadata': extruct.extract(
                response.text,
                response.url,
                syntaxes=['opengraph', 'json-ld']
            ),
        }
```

The above is the code that I have used for web crawling.

This is the command I am trying to run in the command terminal of VS Code
`scrapy crawl imdb --logfile imdb.log -o imdb.jl -t jsonlines`
And this is what is the output I am getting... I am running it in the folder where i have the scrapy.cfg file. Altough I am getting the .jl and the .log file, the JL file seems to be empty so I am not sure where I am going wrong and where can I correct it.

"ScrapyDeprecationWarning: The -t/--output-format command line option is deprecated in favor of specifying the output format within the output URI using the -o/--output or the -O/--overwrite-output option (i.e. -o/-O :). See the documentation of the -o or -O option or the following examples for more information. Examples working in the tutorial: scrapy crawl quotes -o quotes.csv:csv   or   scrapy crawl quotes -O quotes.json:json
feeds = feed_process_params_from_cli("

Comment: just leave off the `-t jsonlines` portion of your command to get rid of the deprecation warning.  But it's only a warning it shouldn't effect the output of the crawl.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce.  When I run your code with the same command it works fine